# Update selected objects from ListView in Django

Tags: django, django-views, django-generic-views, django-forms

I have a ListView in which I list all objects in a table. Every row has a checkbox. I am trying to update the objects whose checkbox is marked with a formset in another view, but I don't know how to send the user to my update view with the post data from the form.

I've tried

```
class MyListView(ListView):
    model = Entry

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return MyUpdateView.as_view(request)
```

I get the error `as_view() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)`. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

See [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/base/#django.views.generic.base.View.as_view) for the correct usage, `as_view` returns a callable

```
class MyListView(ListView):
    model = Entry

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return MyUpdateView.as_view()(request)
```